# Mod Rewrite for a single url parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having difficulty doing a simple mod rewrite. I don't know what I'm doing wrong after countless attempts straight from examples.

Just trying to make this:

```
www.example.com/speaker-lineup-new.php?link=speaker-name
```

Look like this:

```
www.example.com/speaker-lineup-new/speaker-name
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ speaker-lineup-new.php?link=$1 [NC]
```

The above results in all of the website's pages having relative path errors.

I'm using `^(.*)` because I want it to be able to accept any character.

---

**THE FIX**

This was an issue with the way I enabled .htaccess in apache. In my vHost file I had:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/www.example.com/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What I NEEDED to have was:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/www.example.com/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^speaker-lineup-new/(.*) speaker-lineup-new.php?link=$1 [NC]
```

Some apache configurations add trailing slash to this type of addresses - in this case you should add it too.

Comment: No errors on rest of site but I get a 404 on the page I'm trying to rewrite. `The requested URL /speaker-lineup-new/dan-gustafik/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: It looks like this rule is not executed. Is this first rule in .htaccess? You stated, that another rule broke your site, so I assume that mod_rewrite is working correctly. If you are not sure - test it according to @anubhava suggestions from another comment.  You can add info to your question by editing it - it will be more readable than in comments.

Comment: It was a bad apache configuration. Just fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?link=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, No errors on rest of site but I get a 404 on the page I'm trying to rewrite. `The requested URL /speaker-lineup-new/dan-gustafik/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: .htaccess is located in the root directory, there are other rules, but I will try removing the other rules to see if I can pinpoint the issue

Comment: Same result, here are all of the enabled modules in Apache:

Comment: core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 evasive20_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)

Comment: mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 security2_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)

Comment: my vHost config ` <Directory /var/www/html/www.example.com/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>`

Comment: It seems like all my 301s and my www redirects all work. Everything except for rewrites. Maybe a bug in apache. Using Apache/2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If you have other rules in your .htaccess then you must update the question with your latest .htaccess

Comment: It was a bad apache configuration. Thank you for your help and answer.